# Using indentation to make CSS more readable? (making parents and children more identifiable in CSS)

Tags: css, indentation

I've been always guiding myself with the following CSS structure:

```
#nav { }
#nav li { }
#nac li a { }
```

This structure tells me clearly who is the parent and the child.

But in a recent article (I think it was CSS Trick) someone said that CSS is read from right to left. So the more tags I had the slower it will be (and sometimes I think its unnecessary to write every single tag involve in the selector).

So it may be something like this:

```
#nav { }
#special-link { }
```

where **#special-link** is **#nav**'s child. I know this is not a big problem in a simple stylesheet but in a big one I always would get confused about who is who's parent and child.

Another solution would be:

```
#nav { }
   #special-link { }
```

Indentation

How do you solve with this CSS dilemma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say you're optimising prematurely. I read the same article, and at the end, he states that these guidelines were written over ten years ago, when computers had much less power under the bonnet. Now, I really don't think it matters much—compared to any JavaScript you have running, your CSS will be lightning-fast. Go for the readable option.

One way you can make it faster without sacrificing readability is, as Chris Coyier states, to avoid descendants in favour of children. So instead of `#nav li a`, use `#nav > li > a`. This should improve speed and actually conveys more information, not less.

Comment: I agree, the ability to read and understand exactly what's going on is primary when I write CSS. Especially if you have to hand the project off someday.

Comment: I agree with you. The CSS is not the usual suspect when a page takes time to load. It's better to sacrifice a little bit of speed for readability in this case. I'm definately going to use descendants instead of children selectors more than I've done. Some good advices there Samir!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CleverCSS](http://sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss/) - I found it very readable... but that may be because I'm Python developer. Also, it results in ordinary CSS stylesheet.